# Selecting and displaying an icon as a profile picture

Tags: html, css, node.js

I'm working on a messenger group project, and I've been tasked with the profile picture. I want to the user to be able to select an icon and display it as the profile picture.

pfp_colors is a folder with png images of the profile pics available, I am trying to find a way to select and display the image

```
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Logout</a>
                    <a <select class="profile-picture">
                        <option data-content="pfp_colors/blackPFP.png">Black</option>
                        <option data-content="pfp_colors/bluePFP.png">Blue</option>
                        <option data-content="pfp_colors/brownPFP.png">Brown</option>
                        <option data-content="pfp_colors/grayPFP.png">Gray</option>
                        <option data-content="pfp_colors/greenPFP.png">Green</option>
                        <option data-content="pfp_colors/orangePFP.png">Orange</option>
                        <option data-content="pfp_colors/purplePFP.png">Purple</option>
                        <option data-content="pfp_colors/redPFP.png">red</option>
                        <option data-content="pfp_colors/whitePFP.png">white</option>
                        <option data-content="pfp_colors/yellowPFP.png">yellow</option>
                    </select>
                    </a>         
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of data-content, use value attribute for option tag.

I used onchange event on select element so whenever the option will change it will trigger and get the value of the selected option (which is url of image) and then you can inject that url where you want by using `.src` property.

See this:

https://jsfiddle.net/ziaalich/0a3f4xyn/30/

```
     <select class="profile-picture" onchange='getPicture(this)'>
      <option value="https://picsum.photos/50/50">Black</option>
      <option value="https://picsum.photos/50/50">Blue</option>
      <option value="https://picsum.photos/50/50">Brown</option>
      <option value="https://picsum.photos/50/50">Gray</option>
      <option value="https://picsum.photos/50/50">Green</option>
      <option value="https://picsum.photos/50/50">Orange</option>
      <option value="https://picsum.photos/50/50">Purple</option>
      <option value="https://picsum.photos/50/50">red</option>
      <option value="https://picsum.photos/50/50">white</option>
      <option value="https://picsum.photos/50/50">yellow</option>
    </select>
    <img class='profile-image' src='#'>

   const profilePicture = document.querySelector('.profile-image')
    function getPicture(picture) {
      let url = picture.value;
      profilePicture.src = url;
    }
```

Let me know if you have any question

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, but since I have a file of pictures, I don't need to use URLs right? So do I make the values the file paths of my images?

Comment: yes exactly, those files are public so they will be urls after all.Mark the question as solved if it helps u : )